# Is it better process every list element or find elements you want to process first?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list: `List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>();`.

`MyClass` has methods `SetBool` and `IsTrue`. I have to set every object of this list to false (`obj.SetBool(false)`).

There are 2 possible ways:

First:

```
foreach (MyClass obj in MyList)
{
    obj.SetBool(false)
}
```

Second:

```
List<MyClass> MyList2 = MyList.Where(c => c.IsTrue()).ToList();

foreach (MyClass obj in MyList2)
{
    obj.SetBool(false)
}
```

If I use first one it may be slow because it changes every element. The second way can be slow too, because it has to find objects first.

So my question is:
Which one will be faster (I may have very large number of elements in list) and why?

Comment: Why not test the same using a `StopWatch` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest would be the combination:

```
foreach (MyClass obj in MyList)
{
    if (obj.IsTrue())
        obj.SetBool(false)
}
```

But the difference with your first version will only be meaningful when `SetBool()` does some extensive validations or computation, and is much more expensive than `Istrue()`.

Comment: IsTrue is method not field or property.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal You're right, thanks.  It doesn't really change the answer but I fixed it anyway.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal you are right but it does not make great difference now.

Answer (score 2):

**First will be shorter. Second one will be lengthy.**

`Why ?`

Let us say you have 100 items in list.

For first snippet it will iterate over 100 items only.

Whereas for second snippet it will loop over 100 then takeout 15 (let us assume). Then it will iterate over those 15.

So basically it iterated over 115 for a list of 100 items.

Instead you can check this way

```
foreach (MyClass obj in MyList)
{
    if (obj.IsTrue())
        obj.SetBool(false)
}
```

This will iterate over all of them but will call `SetBool()` only where it is true

Answer (score 2):

Even faster one could be (but like everything have to be measured in your specific case) is use of `for`

```
for(int i=0;i<MyList.Count;i++)
{
    if (MyList[i].Istrue())
        MyList[i].SetBool(false)
}
```

All this optimization are **context sensitive**.

A lot depdends on:

- your list size
- true values destribution in that list
- does SetBool method do something "heavy"

Answer (score 1):

it depends, if `SetBool` is an expensive function, then it does matter.
And again, if the `isTrue` is an expensive function, then again, it does matter.

but anyway, instead of using your second way, i would rather use

```
foreach (MyClass obj in MyList.Where(c => c.IsTrue()))
{
    obj.SetBool(false)
}
```

this would decrease speed and memory consumption compared to your implementation.
But again, you have to measure it. if it takes longer to check, if the item IsTrue then setting the object, then just use your first way.
if it is the other way around, then use my method.

in terms of [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), both run in O(n)

Answer (score 0):

For every reasonable implementation of `SetBool` the first version should be faster.